# What is the significance of the ToString() method?

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone please explain this for me, how this even work??

How is it even possible to return anything out of `ToString()`, without creating an actual method?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Person
    {

        private string name;
        private int age;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age; }
            set { age = value; }
        }
        **/*  
         * What is ToString() method?
         * What I am overriding Here?
         */**
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name= " + Name + " Age=" + Age;
        }        
    }
    class Sample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person P1 = new Person();
            P1.Name = "ABC";
            P1.Age = 21;
            Console.WriteLine(P1.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

            **//Ouput Name = ABC Age = 23**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All classes and structs in C# derive implicitly from `System.Object`.  You are overriding `Object.ToString`.

In C#, when you write:

```
class Person
{
```

It's effectively the same as writing

```
class Person : System.Object
{
```

> How is it even possible to return anything out of ToString(), without creating an actual method?

If you don't override `ToString`, you'll get the default implementation provided by `System.Object.ToString()`.

The implicit base class being `System.Object` is documented in 4.2.2 of the C# language spec:

> The object class type is the ultimate base class of all other types. Every type in C# directly or indirectly derives from the object class type.
>
> The keyword object is simply an alias for the predefined class System.Object.

Note that it's slightly different with a custom `struct`, since value types derive from [`System.ValueType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx), but `System.Object` is still part of the inheritance hierarchy.

This is documented in 4.1.1 of the C# language spec:

> All value types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType, which, in turn, inherits from class object. It is not possible for any type to derive from a value type, and value types are thus implicitly sealed (§10.1.1.2).
>
> Note that System.ValueType is not itself a value-type. Rather, it is a class-type from which all value-types are automatically derived.

Answer (score 4):

> how is it even possible to return anything out of ToString(), without creating an actual method

The default implementation of `Object.ToString()` is simply:

```
return GetType().ToString();
```

This returns the (unqualified) name of the type.  If you had not overridden it on your `Person` class, then it would have returned `"Person"`.

Subclasses are free to override this method to return a more useful string, which might include some of the object's state, or even a human-friendly representation of the object.  (`DateTime` does this, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

`public override string` is creating a method, it just happens to already exist, thus the override keyword is used to denote that you are redefining a method in the parent class (System.Object).

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx

> Because all classes in the .NET Framework are derived from Object,
>   every method defined in the Object class is available in all objects
>   in the system. Derived classes can and do override some of these
>   methods, including:
>
> - Equals - Supports comparisons between objects.
> - Finalize - Performs    cleanup operations before an object is automatically reclaimed.
> - GetHashCode - Generates a number corresponding to the value of the    object to support the use of a hash table.
> - ToString - Manufactures a    human-readable text string that describes an instance of the class.